# Highcharts parse CSV

Tags: csv, highcharts

i am sorry if there is somewhere the answer...but i don't understand how to parse a simple CSV-File for Highcharts.

I have this simple CSV-File:

> Date,Site,Sum
>   2013/11/26,NON-US,12345
>   2013/11/26,US,12355
>   2013/11/26,ALL,24700
>   2013/11/28,NON-US,12355
>   2013/11/28,US,12365
>   2013/11/28,ALL,24720

I want a line Chart, but i dont understand how to parse the csv-File correctly...

I want the "Date" in the x-Axis, the "Sum" for the y-Axis and the "Site" as Series.

Can you please help me?

i really need your help! I am completely new to Javascript.

Now i have a code, but i cannot get it run properly:

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Legal'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: []
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Size'
        }
    },
    series: []
};

$.get('test_statistic.csv', function(data) {
// Split the lines
    var lines = data.split('\n');


    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
        var items = line.split(',');


        if (lineNo == 0) {
            $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(items[0]);
            });
        }

        else {
            var series = {
                data: []
            };
            $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                if (itemNo == 0) {
                    series.name = items[1];
                } else {
                    series.data.push(parseFloat(items[2]));
                }
            });

            options.series.push(series);

        }

    });

    // Create the chart
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

i get the following 
[Chart](http://s1.directupload.net/images/131202/fqk5fdbj.jpg)

BR
Philipp

Comment: which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify script from here: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-file-csv-xml-json#1 but dates need to be parsed, by split function, which allows to extract each day/month and then use Date.UTC() functon which returns timestamp (correct format of date for highcharts)

Comment: I advice to familiar with javascript (not JAVA, it is not the same) and how to use arrays. I point you which function you need so Im not sure where the problem is.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure where do you use suggestion from my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for options to read CSV files, [SuperCSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net) is the best one. you have very well documented examples which can make you working within minutes.

About making charts as per your requirements is pretty much simple.
Using SuperCSV, you can parse the data and convert into beans `http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/io/CsvBeanReader.html`

Once you have converted into beans, you can use Jackson to convert the bean data to json format [Tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/json/jackson/convert-java-object-to-from-json-using-jackson-example/) and according to [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/), you can use JSON data to easily build the graphs